# Does keycloak rest api query have Not condition

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, keycloak-services

Keycloak REST API allows to list the users :
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms//users

and what is more useful to filter users with a query like:
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms//users?firstName=Test

Is it possible to write the query with Excluding condition? For example :

http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms//users?firstName!=AnyName  ( that example not working and in response, the whole list of users returns ). Or I understand that it's a "rocket science" but might be like   http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms//users?role!=Admin ...

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is **No**. But you can create custom REST endpoints as mentioned [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_extensions_rest).

**See also:**

REST API document:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/7.0/rest-api/#_users_resource

Source code:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/b4b3527df7656bfaaee351ec414e56c683c134c2/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java#L179

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I'm more in .Net, more simple to me is just to implement some wrapper (Facade) around simple List() results in that case. It's quite strange to have a "max" param and not start from or some other pagination. How to get other records on another side after that nice default constant of 100 ( default value) without bringing your limit :) ?

Comment: Query parameter `&first=0&max=20` can get first 20 users ordered by user name. `&first=20&max=20` can get 2nd 20 users. `&first=40&max=20` can get 3rd 20 users.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Still Not clear how to get the total number of users. How I can show pagination when I don't know how many records I have. And of course found that it's not possible to sort items before get N of them.

Comment: You can get the total number of users by `http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/users/count`.

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA how can I apply custom attribute filters to that count endpoint? I don't want a total of all users but rather a total for filtered users by their custom attribute